# How to do this in selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I'm new in Selenium and I need your help. I was trying to run a test for creating a new tab and put a new page. I was using a CSS selector, but it didn't work. The console shows me: `stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document`.

Here is a piece of the code:

```
@FindBy (css=".list-group > a[id=\"itemc\"]")
    private List<WebElement> categories;
    @FindBy (css="body")
    private WebElement googleBar;
    public void testClick() {
        contactLink.click();
    }   
    public void moveTab(String web){
        googleBar.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "t");
        for(WebElement category : categories) {
        driver.get(web);
        w.waitForElementToBeVisible(driver,contactLink, 2);
        category.click();
    
        }
    }
```

The test is here:

```
package tests;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import pages.BlazeBasePage;
import testrunner.BaseTest;

public class test3 extends BaseTest{
     @Test
     public void verify3() {
          getLogger().info("Starting Second test"); 
          // we initialize the different methods and tags 
          BlazeBasePage basePage = new BlazeBasePage(driver);
          basePage.moveTab("https://demoblaze.com/");               
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To open a new tab and a page on it, you can use a JavaScript executor:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.open()");//open new tab
ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));//switch tabs
```

**Remember:** `tabs.get(0)` is the first tab and `tabs.get(1)` is the second etc... Like in Java arrays.

Comment: thanks buddy I can solve it I used this command driver.switchTo().newWindow(WindowType.Tab)